# Is this inequality true for Ramsey Numbers $R(n,n) - n \geq R(n,n-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Is this inequality true for Ramsey Numbers $R(n,n) - n \geq R(n,n-1)$. It  seems like this is plausible, but i'm not really sure how to show it is or is not true. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true for $n=2$ since $R(2,1)=1$ and $R(2,2)=2$.
However, the statement holds for larger $n$. Have your tried anything ?

Comment: Potter, I've been trying to find graph theory / combinatorial ways to approach it, but I've not really had any ideas which were good. I was thinking about using induction, but i'm not sure if it is applicable here.